# PhpStorm: disable class properties autosort

Tags: phpstorm

The issue is PhpStorm auto sorts class properties and methods on code reformatting (<kbd>CTRL+ALT+L</kbd>).

Version 2020.2, Ubuntu.

Does anybody know how to disable this?

Comment: You may have used `Reformat File...` action instead by mistake (similar shortcut: `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L`) and those settings were remembered. Double check what settings you have got there (as it has an option for "Rearrange code" there)

Comment: @LazyOne I understand the difference between code reformat and code rearrange and file reformat. **Code reformat** makes autosort.

Comment: 1) So .. did you resolve it? 2) If you did not -- check my prev comment again. Or should I explain it differently?

Comment: @LazyOne no I have not. I said that you explanation is minor.

Comment: Well...OK. 1) Use `Code | Reformat File...` -- It will show a dialog with few options (what to reformat and extra options): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#reformat_file . One of those extra options is `Rearrange entries`. 2) If you reformat code with that option enabled, it will be **remembered and applied** even when you use `Code | Reformat Code...`. THEREFORE, please check your options in `Code | Reformat File...` dialog -- ensure that the appropriate rearrange option is DISABLED there because it gets applied even in "normal" code reformat.

Comment: More on Reformat File dialog: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/reformat-file-dialog.html